# Regex for 8 digits non repeating numbers

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, reactjs, regex

I want to make a regex for 8 digit non-repeating regex for phone number. It should not match with 11111111 or 22222222 .... 88888888

I tried to make  a Regex but it only matches for 1

Example - `^(?!.*([0-9])1{7})[0-9]{8}$`

What corrections do I need in this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
^(\d)(?!\1{7})\d{7}$
```

Capture the first digit and then ensure that it is not repeated 7 more times.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gz3iux/4)

Answer (score 4):

You can add this to your script js:

```
function UpdateInput2(fun = '12345678') {    
arr = fun.split('');

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
    //for unique constant
    regex = /^(\d)(?!\1{7})\d{7}/g;
    str = fun;
    index = str.search(regex);
    fun = replaceIndex(fun, index, str[index] + '*');

}

$("#output").val(fun);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
function isDigitRepeat(n) {
    const regex = /^(\d)(?!\1{7})\d{7}/g;
    return regex.test(n)
}
```